# Would a tag cleaning campaign be a good idea for AU too?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just stumbled over a post in meta-superuser:

https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5718/tag-cleanup-for-january-2014?cb=1

It looks like they have tag cleaning campaigns on a regular basis. Might this be something useful for AU too?

Comment: Is alive! [Cleanup 2014: A tale of tag cleaning](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8159)