# Blacklist the [installation] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-block-request

We've [created two tags to separate questions](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7820/169736) that are about installing Ubuntu and installing something in Ubuntu: [system-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-installation) and [software-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-installation). This is with the purpose of getting rid [of the install tag](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7819/169736).

There are over **12k instances (and growing! it's the 2nd most popular tag)** that need to be **disambiguated manually**, so I've doing this mostly organically and it takes forever. Granted, it could go quicker if we set our collective minds to it, but we don't want to fill the front page with that so we'd keep doing a handful at a time.

Unfortunately, the questions keep coming in. I try to catch them early but some always fall through the cracks.

Please blacklist [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation) (and its numerous synonyms) so that we can clean up the remaining occurrences. The tag wiki and excerpt for [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation) clearly states what tags to use instead.

[(Copied shamelessly from Gilles petition in UL, with some modifications)](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2532/41104)

> [image]

Comment: @Briam I've been attempting to help clean this up and received the following guidance "it would be best to do that once you reach 2k rep, otherwise your edits would end up being rejected. otherwise, also make substantial changes to the post(but only when necessary)." Is this the consensus? The work obviously needs doing and the vast majority have been approved. I'm baffled. Should I open a new question? It seems to be rather substantially connected to this one.

Comment: @ElderGeek read the "rules of participation" in [this question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8159/169736)

Comment: Thank You. I have done so and it seems to substantially cover what I'm doing. I added the Installation tag to that post to the best of my ability, although from the 12 upvotes to the answer below it would seem we have a fairly clear consensus already, yes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is done. Attempting to use this tag - or edit any post that currently uses it - will result in the following error:

[image: The 'installation' tag is not allowed. Please use either system-installation or software-installation]

Which also links to this discussion: [Should we split the installation tag into seperate tags for the installation of Ubuntu and the installation of software?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7820/should-we-split-the-installation-tag-into-seperate-tags-for-the-installation-of)

Y'all might want to add further guidance there.

Comment: A million upvotes on you and your family.