# Synonym request: [software-uninstall] to [uninstall]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

We have two tags:

- [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) - lots of questions
- [software-uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-uninstall) - handful of questions

Both of these tags are for questions relating to uninstalling software.

Can we merge the contents of [software-uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-uninstall) into [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) and then make the former a synonym of the latter?

Comment: I would check those with uninstall since some are about uninstalling plugins, Windows (the OS), Ubuntu, uninstall the internet (yeah, I'm not joking), [uninstall the installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall+installation) (I wonder how), etc. I would review the tag before doing anything (BTW, the tag if anything should be instead separated on software-uninstallation and system-uninstallation... or just use software/system-installation since the method of installation will tell you how to uninstall it).

Comment: Whether the [tag:uninstall] tag needs cleaning up as well is not the topic of this post! (The [tag:uninstall] tag *does*, in fact, need cleaning up)

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any reason for moving a group of questions about a specific topic (software uninstallation) into a more general category (the [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) tag). If your goal is to make a more fitting tag for those questions about the uninstallation of software, retag them as [software-uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-uninstall) if they're tagged [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall), if they all can't be merged.

Comment: Yeah... there are only 1011 [tag:uninstall] questions to check whether they need to be retagged to [tag:software-uninstall]... I think I would get fed up after 5...

Comment: @wilf then ask for it to be blacklisted. Like I did with uninstall.

Comment: I meant [installition](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8233/blacklist-the-installation-tag)