# Maybe change the tag description for [uninstall]

Tags: discussion, tags

Related to [Synonym request: [software-uninstall] to [uninstall]](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8313/synonym-request-software-uninstall-to-uninstall):

To help with choosing the right tag, between [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) and [software-uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-uninstall) maybe the tag description for [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) should be changed?

Current [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) description:

> Questions about uninstalling software in Ubuntu, or uninstalling Ubuntu from a computer.

Suggested [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) description:

> Questions about uninstalling Ubuntu from a computer.

Comment: This makes sense - I've suggested edits to the tags.

Comment: I agree with both NateT's and Zanna's answers. The `uninstall` tag serves no actual purpose and can cause more harm than good, so it should be merged with `software-uninstall`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for a tag about uninstalling Ubuntu itself. One does not uninstall an operating system but simply installs over it or erases the disk.

Generally I use the tag [software-uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-uninstall) rather than [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall), but there is no reason for us to have both of these tags. I suggest keeping [software-uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-uninstall) and making [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) a synonym of it and merging them.

Comment: I agree, this would be the best solution...

Answer (score 3):

I've gotta say, I just looked at the related link, and I disagree with the consensus. Sure, [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) is technically a more general category, but within the context of valid questions on AU, I am not so sure. Everything inside the OS is software.

Sure, there are a lot of instances of firmware/hardware questions that are within the AU scope, but firmware/hardware uninstall questions? I can't think of any, at least not any that are valid.

If appropriate use of a tag encourages poor questions (e.g. "uninstall the internet itself?" as in one of the linked page's comments, supposedly a real example??), isn't it doing more harm than good?