# Can we fix this tag or should we just [uninstall]?

Tags: discussion, tags

It's [been asked about before](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8313/synonym-request-software-uninstall-to-uninstall) and [asked about again](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19968/maybe-change-the-tag-description-for-uninstall) but it seems like the large [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) tag is still a bit of a miscellany, with the majority of questions in it being about uninstalling software, while we have another [software-uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-uninstall) tag.

What should we do with these tags?

Should we merge [software-uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-uninstall) into [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) and clean it up?

Or should we merge [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) into [software-uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-uninstall), creating other tags such as [system-uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-uninstall) as/if needed?

Or should we get rid of both of them? Are there any experts on *uninstalling* stuff? Anyone interested in following these tags? Could the tasks of uninstalling currently gathered loosely in [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) be considered to be better covered by other tags such as [package-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/package-management), [software-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-installation), [apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/apt), [system-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-installation), [dual-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual-boot), etc?

Or should we do something else entirely? :)

Comment: Personal thoughts: it sounds like `uninstall` is a meta-tag, and so is `software-uninstall` or a proposed `system-uninstall`.  Ideally we should burninate the uninstall tag and have the corresponding removal questions be put in the *proper* sections rather than having a larger 'meta-tag' for uninstalling software or system generally.

Comment: yeah, my vote is for removing them both

Comment: @ThomasWard package-management covers software installation/uninstallation/reinstallation using package managers. Unless the user can't identity a package manager or is doing everything from source, that fits.

Answer (score 2):

Since uninstalling software can be broadly considered as part of software installation, I propose that we make both [software-uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-uninstall) and [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) tags synonyms of the [software-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-installation) tag.

Similarly, since "uninstalling a system" doesn't make much sense as a term and since it can be broadly considered as part of system installation, I also propose that we make [system-uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-uninstall) a synonym of [system-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-installation).

I believe it's better that we don't get rid of the tags completely, rather make the above synonyms, as it seems that quite many users use these tags, and even if we remove them, chances are that someone will create them again.

Comment: Makes sense, this seems like the best option

Comment: software-uninstall and uninstall have been synonymized to software-installation, as have remove and removal which were synonymized to uninstall. I did not bother to synonymize system-uninstall as I don't expect it to be created (does not exist on date). Tag wiki & excerpt to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) tag is too broad. It's a big tag that currently has 2,262 questions.

I don't mind creating a new [system-delete](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-delete) or [system-uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-uninstall) tag though. It would be another big tag. Searching for "Ubuntu install" questions returns 476 results. I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be possible to request in the tag wiki excerpt to restrict the [system-uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-uninstall) tag to be used only for currently supported versions of Ubuntu and its officially supported flavors.

Comment: How do you "uninstall" a system.

Comment: @Braiam Maybe I  should call it system-delete.

Comment: I'm asking how do you accomplish said task, not how should it be called. Because, and I'm sure you know, no sane OS allows you to remove itself from within, because it would leave the system unusable.

Comment: An Ubuntu user could use [OS-Uninstaller](https://askubuntu.com/q/1293835/) to accomplish this task safely without deleting his data. OS-Uninstaller is a component of Boot-Repair. My question for you is do you think it's OK to use system-uninstaller for a tag name and system-delete for a tag synonym?

Comment: 1) That question is about "OS-Uninstaller" not about os uninstallation. 2) OS-Unistaller is a glorified table partition editor, which unlike others, don't allow you to modify, create or format partitions. Just delete them. 3) In concept, there's no OS uninstaller, because such thing makes no sense. You just remove all partitions/format the disk and optionally install a OS afresh.