# Why is the Installation tag recommended for software installs?

Tags: discussion

So I was editing a question [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477060/cannot-install-software-center)

Why does AU still recommend the tag `installation` when it is an inappropriate tag to begin with?

Comment: According to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206907/how-are-suggested-tags-chosen the title and question text are examined to determine relevant tags. I would assume that since the post in question uses the words Ubuntu, install, and Installation it prompted the appearance of the [tag:installation] tag.

Comment: There are currently over 12,000 questions using this tag so the tag can't be deleted so the questions would have to manually be retagged as either software-installation or system-installation first. I'm guessing as long as the tag exists the system will auto suggest it.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that the tag should be deleted.  While, yes the method use is great, the thought of Software-center, would provoke a different tag response.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it be deleted, just pointing out that the system doesn't know not to use it. I agree that it's weird that software-center wasn't chosen instead given the amount of times it was mentioned.

Comment: it twas removed by moderator

Comment: @unorthodoxgrammar - don't worry, only 11908 now...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the `installation` tag should be disabled for any *new* questions or edits (instead of simply being deleted). This would allow for a progressive manual clean-up of the relevant questions, without any new questions with this tag being added to the list.

I'm not sure though that the Stack Exchange software allows something like that.

PS I've been battling the `installation` tag for some time now, but in my experience there are more new questions with this tag in a period of time than the number of questions that I can triage with the more appropriate `software-installation` or `system-installation`.

Comment: Do you know that there can't be new questions with the [installation tag](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/9047/169736)

Comment: Nope, this is new to me. And must be rather recent. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @Braiam was this updated to reflect my question here on Meta?

Comment: @Virusboy - if u mean the thing to stop the `installation` tag - no its been around for a while - see [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/9047/178596)